# iOS Button Vector Image doesn't automatically adjust to screen size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently trying to introduce myself to Xcode, IB and Vector images. I am struggling with the auto layout and having the buttons adjust to screen size.

As you can see the buttons are same size in the iPhone 6s and iPad Pro.

[image: iPhone 6s]

And here is the iPad Pro 12.9" size of the buttons:

[image: iPad Pro]

The vector images I use are universal .pdf images at the size of 50x41. And here are the settings to those:

[image: settings]

How do I get these images to adjust properly from screen size to screen size?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/vector-assets-in-ios-xcode/

Answer (score 0):

What constraints do you have to change the size of the imageView? I would expect to see a constraint between the top two images (and the bottom two) that forces a constant gap.

The constraints on each image's width should then have a lower priority so they get stretched on a bigger screen. Then you want to constrain the height of each image to its width so they stay 1:1 (I'm guessing), and therefore stretch vertically if they are stretched horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIImageView content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspctFit and set AutoLayout constraints on the container for aspect ratios rather than just spacing and fixed sizes.